# Eigen value of an interval matrix in matlab

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

A matrix, whose each element is any arbitary interval, is called interval matrix. I need to generate a code to find its eigen value.Can anyone answer this??

Comment: What's an eigenvalue of such a matrix? And what are we supposed to answer? You didn't even pose a question.

Comment: I need to generate the code, how to calculate the eigen value of an Interval Matrix..

Comment: What does it mean for something to be an eigenvalue of an interval matrix?

Comment: By Matlab finding eigen value of a matrix is very easy...just use the term eig(A) for any matrix A...Here this A matrix is an interval matrix, whose each elements are intervals...so  now I need to find a code for eigen values of such matrices..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a matrix A you can find the vector containing its eigenvalues by:

```
eig(A)
```

if it's what are you asking. For further information you can refer to matlab documentation which is given here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/

Comment: no here the matrix is interval matrix..as I defined earlier